# Modify a text field fieldwhile reading its value

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to edit a textfield, if a condition is verified, a blank is added before the text field i tried to write this but it's totally wrong.

```
<textFieldExpression>

  <![CDATA[if ($F{cond1}.equals("K")) $F{LIGREF} = " "+$F{LIGREF}]]>

</textFieldExpression>
```

Any one has an idea please?
i tried also to look in style tag attributes i didn't find leftMargin and things like that.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can use ternary operation

Comment: @AlexK thank you for reply but have you a useful link or something i can read about it

Comment: @AmirakGL Sample: `$F{cond1}.equals("K") ? " " + $F{LIGREF} : $F{LIGREF}`

Comment: @AlexK many thanks it's the write answer, so add it to mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator%28%3F%3A%29).

In your case the expression will be:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cond1}.equals("K") ? " " + $F{LIGREF} : $F{LIGREF}]]></textFieldExpression>
```